# Java for loops null pointer

Tags: java, for-loop, nullpointerexception

I have the class Memory which is a list of blocks, and Blocks which is a list of tuples and Tuple.

```
Memory m;
for(Block b:m.blocklist){
    for (Tuple t:b.tuplelist){
        //do something
    }
}
```

The above code works fine, every single tuple goes through it but the problem is even after the last tuple, it continues on leading to a **null pointer exception**. I can't modify the memory class, blocks nor tuples so how do I avoid the error?

Comment: Would it help to check if the block or tuple you get from the list is null?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could've sworn I tried this myself but for some reason it didn't work "-_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that the NPE appears on the line of the second for you can add a check for null:

```
Memory m;
for(Block b:m.blocklist){
   if (b != null) {
     for (Tuple t:b.tuplelist){
        //do something
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If one of the blocks is null, you'll get an NPE.

Check for null:

```
Memory m;
for(Block b:m.blocklist){
    if (b != null) {
        for (Tuple t:b.tuplelist){
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in the last Blocklist the Tuplelist is null?